# Set page title from 2sxc dnn module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

How can I change page title from module razor code?
I have news module on page site.name/news,
and it is called with news id eg.:
site.name/news/newid
In this page I display different news and I also want to set
different html title for each of this pages.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, another option is to do it through JS

advantages

1. future-compatible when dnn moves to mvc
2. still google compliant

disadvantage

1. not in the html for any external services which don't parse JS, like facebook

Comment: oh yes - that was just one of my sessions last week at the DNN Connect. Search for "2sxc translate" and you'll get a blog hit with a title. the blog itself adds the title in JS

Comment: I would definitely favor server-side for anything seo-relevant if you can do it without a ton of extra effort. Crawling source as delivered from a server is always going to be the easiest thing to do, Google changes their mind about stuff a lot, and they're not the only search engine.

Answer (score 1):

I already find the answer here: https://sexycontent.codeplex.com/discussions/547134

```
@{
    var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    page.Title = "Sample";
}
```